# Secure alternatives to fingerprint-verified TLS on ESP8266 for MQTT or REST communications?

Tags: rest, security, mqtt, tls1.2, esp8266

MQTT or REST from an ESP8266 without TLS is risky. Passing unencrypted credentials and tokens around doesn't strike me as being terribly secure. But TLS communications on the ESP8266 requires a large chunk of memory, and to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks you really have to verify the server certificate, generally done using an SHA1 fingerprint. But the SHA1 fingerprint will change as the server certificate changes, so hard-coding it isn't an option. Asking a user to go and find their SHA1 certificate fingerprint using their browser dev tools and insert it into a web config portal is pretty much a no-no too.

Has anyone come up with a workable solution to this conundrum? One which delivers excellent security with greatest genericity, soft settings and least user-involvement? What's the best way of effortlessly achieving a high level of security for outside-firewall communications on an ESP8266?

Comment: Idea: add new certificate fingerprint to array as long as the old is still valid - therefore a api might be useful

Answer (score 1):

The ESP8266 Arduino project introduced verifying with root CA certificates which is heaps better than using fingerprints. They have an example of it for GitHub here: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/HTTPSRequestCACert